# Multiple files download on IE8 with Servlets

Tags: jquery, jsf, servlets, richfaces

I am trying to build a web app which can download multiple files on the client (not in a zip file).
I'm using jsf, jquery and servlets.
The code works fine in Mozilla but does not work in IE8.

To be more specific: i want the client to receive 4 different save/open promts from the browser. So ... i made a simple example like this:
user presses the Action button >> 4 different iframes will be created with the src attribute equals to servlet path >> the servlet generates a response with a pdf file >> the client receives multiple save/open promts

This works fine in Mozilla but in IE8 if you push fast enough the ESC key you will get 3 save/open promts :) which is not enough... 
I have checked to see if all the 4 requests and all 4 responses are made and they are all there ... I can't see where is the problem with the prompts ...

Is there any way to make the jquery wait untill the promt is closed to make the next iframe (request)? I think this should work even in IE :)

In this example there are 4 pdfs created with JasperReports.

Servlet:

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 509291005008276860L;
private Logger logger LoggerFactory.getLogger( TestServlet.class );

@Override
protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp ) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    try {

        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        params.put( "JUDET", "Alba" );
        params.put( "NUME", "Caliman" );
        params.put( "PRENUME", "Victor" );
        params.put( "DATA_NASTERE", "01/03/1987" );
        params.put( "LOCALITATE", "Alba Iulia" );
        params.put( "STR", "T. Vladimirescu" );
        params.put( "NR", "11" );
        params.put( "BL", "V4" );
        params.put( "SC", "A" );
        params.put( "ET", "1" );
        params.put( "AP", "1" );
        params.put( "JUDET_DOMICILIU", "Alba" );
        params.put( "TIP_ACT", "CI" );
        params.put( "SERIA", "Ax" );
        params.put( "NR_ACT", "42910" );
        params.put( "CNP", "1870301011193" );
        params.put( "COR", "Inginer software" );
        params.put( "BENEFICIAR", 0 );
        params.put( "EVIDENTA", 0 );
        params.put( "DATA", "02/08/2012" );

        PdfData pdfData = new PdfData();
        pdfData.setExportedFileName( "cerereDosar.pdf" );
        pdfData.setTemplateName( "reports/cerereDosar.jasper" );
        pdfData.setParams( params );

        InputStream inputStream = null;

        resp.reset();
        resp.setHeader( "Content-Type", "application/octet-stream" );
        resp.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + pdfData.getExportedFileName() + "\";" );

        inputStream = new ClassPathResource( pdfData.getTemplateName() ).getInputStream();

        //          final Locale locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getDefaultLocale();
        //          pdfData.getParams().put( JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, new Loca );

        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport( inputStream, pdfData.getParams(),
            new JREmptyDataSource() );

        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream( jasperPrint, resp.getOutputStream() );

        inputStream.close();

        logger.info( req.getQueryString() );
    }
    catch( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

and test.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
xmlns:nao="http://nao.anofm.org/jsf/composite/util"
xmlns:naocc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components">
<ui:composition template="/layout/template.xhtml">
<ui:define name="content">
    <h:form id="forma">
        <a4j:commandButton value="Action" onclick="printTest();" />
        <div style="display: none;" id="result"></div>
    </h:form>

    <script type="text/javascript">     

                function print(tipAct){
                    $('<iframe>')
                    .appendTo('#result')
                    .attr('src', 'http://localhost:8080/nao-inregistrare/TestServlet/')
                    .attr('id', tipAct);
                }

                function printTest(){
                    for(var i = 1; 5>i; i++){
                        $.when(print(i)).done();
                        }
                }

</script>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

Any suggestions are welcomed!

Comment: I'm not sure of the correct solution but what if you use a timer to slow down the individual requests getting fired.  A few seconds might be enough to get it to work in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I got really busy this weekend and forgat to post the answer.
As it turns out the javascript window object is losing  focus on every promt (I knew that but it seems i`m getting realy lazy :( and start asking people to do my work )... so i can make a request / focus gained. This is a very unprofessional and "first try" example but it tricks IE :)

```
var i = 4;

window.onfocus = function(){
if(b == true && i != 0){
print(i);
} else {
alert('i`m done');
}
}

var b;

function print(tipAct){
i--;
b = true;
$('<iframe>')
.appendTo('#result')
.attr('src', 'http://localhost:8080/nao-inregistrare/TestServlet/')
.attr('id', tipAct);
}
```

The var i = 4; stands for the loop in the printTest() function wich i deleted.
On every request/focus gained i decrements in the print() function.
The var b is a flag to indicate if this is the first focus and the action button has not been pressed.
And i also changed the action in the button:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Action" onclick="print(i);" />
```

But a question still remains: 
Where is Waldo? (the 4th file from the first example)
A normal flow, in the first example, as i see it would be like this:

1) 1st file gets promted and the rest get lost somewhere
or
2) all 4 files get promted

IE promts a random number of files and never all of them. I am really confused.
When i get some free time i will post this on the microsoft forums ... maybe they have a logical explanation for this.
I'll put a link here too for you guys. :)